# Making a career switch without my current employer knowing

Tags: career-development, career-switch

I am currently employed at a company temporarily. My term ends come the start of 2014. Naturally, I am looking and applying for jobs. I am going to a career fair later this week and my current company will have representatives there. (My current employer doesn't know explicitly that I am looking for a new job but I suppose it would be natural for them to assume I am). Would it be inappropriate or wrong to talk to the rep at the career fair about available positions (given I'm already in the company)?. And just to make it clear, yes I ***should*** talk to my boss about opportunities but there has not been a time to discuss it.

Comment: Talk to your boss ASAP about whether or not the company thinks it should extend your stay. Do it before the fair. Then you can go to it with a clear conscience.

Comment: they cannot extend my stay in the position I'm currently in. I would have to look for a new position.

Comment: I would go to the fair with the clearest conscience ever, then. You have to earn your bread and they know that soon you won't be there.

Comment: `there has not been a time to discuss it` -- Translation: "I have been too apprehensive about breaching the subject with my manager, so I have not made time."  -- Make time now.

Answer (score 10):

I see nothing wrong with attending a career fair and talking to anyone there - including your current employer.

You indicate that your contract ends at the end of the year, and that "they cannot extend my stay in the position I'm currently in. I would have to look for a new position", so it would be reasonable for your current boss to expect you to look for a new job.

I'm not sure why you put "without my current employer knowing" in the Title for your question. When I hire contractors I always expect them to be readying their next gig (on their own time of course - not on my time).

I would however, urge you to talk to your boss first:

- It's common courtesy
- You boss may be in a position to help you find a job within her/his company. Having a recommendation from your current boss is huge! I always interview candidates which have been referred by someone within my company if there is even the slightest chance that they might fit the requirements
- Your boss may be in a position to help you find a job outside of his/her company (we bosses often know people who are hiring elsewhere). If I can't have you work for me, and I like you, I'd be happy to help you find a good job working for friends of mine. I've done this many times.

Answer (score -1):

it is generally understood that temps need to look for their next job. That being said, when companies hire temps they want you to do 'X' and don't want to be bothered. As far as going to a career fair. Absolutely. Why wouldn't you? You have no income at the end of the year.

generally speaking it is not worth the risk to tell your boss you are looking for other work outside the company. The next part is a judgement call. If you think your boss is trustworthy, telling him you are looking for other work in the company can help. However, I have seen cases where managers are all about themselves and companies hire temps so they can fire temps, so if there is any doubt, there is no doubt. If you look for other work in your company it will definitely get back to your manager since they will want a reference.